# How to filter logcat with regex AND operation?

Tags: android, regex, android-studio, adb, logcat

We can easily filter the logcat logs with `OR` operations in regex like,

```
TAG | message
```

I wonder how can I do filtering with multiple `AND` operation? something like,

```
TAG & message1 & message2
```

Here I expect to filter logs which has tag `TAG` and contains both `message1` and `message2` as substring. How to do that?